# How to add more than one condition in a propertygroup?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a property right now that looks like this.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhoneSimulator' ">
```

I now want to add another `Condition` in there looking like this:

```
Condition=" '$(SolutionFileName)' == 'SolutionName.AppNameOne.sln'"
```

How do I add more than one condition inside this propertygroup?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use "And" for multiple conditions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions

Example:
`Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And '$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' == '.vbproj'"`